# Extracting IMDb Movie Images

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am currently doing a small project to create my own version of IMDb search engine using a recommender system. I would like to have img source in my dataset for later usage and I am having a bit of trouble trying to get src links. What I want is a list of all of the img src's so I can slap it onto my dataset. This is what I have so far.

```
images = []
for i in ddf['link']:
    r = requests.get(i)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
    link = soup.find(itemprop="image")
    if link is None:
        images.append(np.nan)
    else:
        images.append(link.attrs['src'])
```

I tried running it for about 5 hours and have not given any results. Please let me know if there are any errors in my code or even a better way of getting them.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: we need the link or relevant html. If sharing html use the snippet tool via [edit] not images. Also, do none of these: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbeautifulsoup%5D+imdb+images  meet your requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do this assuming ddf['link'] consists of movie pages (e.g., https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120338/).

If the movie page has a poster, grab the poster, or return null value.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import numpy as np

images = []
for i in ddf['link']:
    r = requests.get(i)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
    try:
      image_url = page_html.find('div', class_='poster').img['src']
    except:
      image_url = np.nan
    images.append(image_url)
```

If you want to monitor this process, you could have print statements and clear the output.

e.g.,

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import numpy as np
from IPython.core.display import clear_output

images = []

for i in ddf['link']:
  r = requests.get(i)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
  try:
    image_url = page_html.find('div', class_='poster').img['src']
  except:
    image_url = np.nan
  images.append(image_url)
  print(image_url)
  clear_output(wait=True)
```

Comment: Thank you for response! I'm on my 3rd hour running the cell. Will definitely update on this as soon as I get something

Comment: @JamesLee Great let me know if this answered your question :)

Comment: @JamesLee Has this worked for you?